# Youku.com seekTo Precision

Tags: youtube-api, youku

I have been tasked to create a Video player which will play a portion of YouKu video (the Chinese Alternative to YouTube)

To accomplish this, I am using the seekTo function of the YouKu API 
and stop the video using a looping timer that constantly checks where the playhead is using the currentTime API function.

I have created the identical code for the YouTube player, and am noticing a considerable difference in the precision of the stop times between the two video hosts.

YouTube seams to give me quite a good accuracy.  When I tell it to stop at 7.45 seconds for instance, the player will stop very close to that number (usually within .5 seconds)

YouKu on the other hand is very inaccurate - stopping sometimes 3 seconds after I have told it to stop.

Can someone explain to me why this might be?  I am guessing that it has something to do with the i-frame encoding of the videos after they have been uploaded.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
If you have any extra details / knowledge about YouKu, that would also be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: A possible explanation might be network delays? Is the API controlling the playing working on a local player instance, or manipulating the http(s) stream?

Comment: You might want to look into mediaelement.js. It's for youtube and others, but might also be helpful/inspirational for you. I have built a media player using it. You might want to have a look at http://quir.li It probably supports part of what you want to accomplish already. You are free to use it.